# Generating Video from images

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation

I am working on generating `.mp4` Video from array of Images with some transition effect. Is there any Library of SDK is available for this. Please help.

Please check the below video URL about what I am looking for.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/242azi2totylmaa/Screen%20Recording.mov?dl=0

This video I have generated from one demo I got on Github but it is only playing the images with the transition effect but I want to generate `.MP4` video.

If anybody knows the solution please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by using [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideocompositioncoreanimationtool) and AVAssetExportSession from AVFoundation Framework to create video from images with animation.

Here is nice tutorial under the section [Roger Rabbit, Eat Your Heart Out — Add Animation to Videos](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos)